# Create a Button Loading State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button which does a API call. I want to show a loading state while it is loading the data

This is how they handle the network request in the react documentation

```
function simulateNetworkRequest() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
}
```

And this is what I need

```
  function simulateNetworkRequest () {
    return new Promise(axios.post('http://localhost:5000/'))
  }
```

But it it throws this error:

**TypeError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.post(...) is not a function**

Comment: `import axios from 'axios'` did you do this?

Comment: Maybe i am wrong , but doesnt axios already return a promise?

Comment: Your title seems a little misleading, you're trying to fix an error in your request, the loading state doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere in the question.

Comment: Are you sending post requests without a body?

Comment: You can just return `axios.post('http://localhost:5000/')` as it's already returning a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Create an async function to retrieve data from the api

create loading state in functional component :

```
...
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
const [data, setData] = React.useState([])

async function simulateNetworkRequest() {
  setLoading(true)
  const dataFetched = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000')
  setData(dataFetched)
  setLoading(false) //When it's finished
}

if (loading) return <p>Loading ...</p>

return (
 <div>
  {data.map(item => <p>item</p>)}
 </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button that changes his state, you can use like this

```
import * as React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/")
      .then(response => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        //set some data from response
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        //handle error
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="button" onClick={() => handleClick()}>
        {isLoading ? `Loading` : `get data`}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```